# Importing Self Signed certificate from a windows store to Firefox

Tags: wcf, firefox, ssl

So I'm having a problem with certificates and Firefox. I have created an application (WCF service) that runs on the users machine and interacts with a website using web requests. The Requests need to be Https as a requirement and I have the certificate generation set up so it will add the certificates required to the windows certificate store where they are then binded to the port the service is listening on. This is working fine for Chrome/IE but Firefox it does not as it is using it's own store.

The commands I run first set up a local Certificate Authority which will then generate my self signed cert. The final command will bind this cert to the port in use by the wcf service E.G 8502
These are the commands I have been running to generate the certs:

```
makecert.exe -n "CN=TestCA" -pe -ss Root -sr LocalMachine -sky exchange -m 120 -a sha1 -len 2048 -r

makecert.exe -n "CN=localhost" -pe -ss My -sr LocalMachine -sky exchange -m 120 -in "TestCA" -is Root -ir LocalMachine -a sha1 -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1

netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:8502 certhash=‎<Self signed cert thumbprint> appid=<new guid>
```

The Self signed cert generated will look like the following:
[image]

How would I get firefox to import these certs or is there a way I can get firefox to mimic this process and use the same port?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing your certificates manually in Firefox? Options > Advanced > Certificates > View Certificates > Import

Comment: I have tried this, but it will not work. The only way I have gotten it to work is by adding an exception for that specific port at which point it will add the cert itself to the store. Besides these are both manual methods of adding and I need this to be automatic.